# Google Cloud Function Cold Starts With UI Elements

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cold-start

I am currently making an app for both web and iOS and on the web side I have a bunch of logic in Javascript that alters a Firestore database I have. I figured I would move this logic into multiple cloud functions so that I can call them from both my web and iOS client and only have to write the logic once, in nodeJS instead of writing the same logic once for the web app in Javascript and once for the iOS app in Swift. I have gotten the cloud functions to work and update the database but the problem is the cold start times. I have UI elements on my webpage that watch for updates in my Firestore database and change whenever there is a change. Before these changes would be instantaneous but now with Cloud Functions I have to wait for the cold start to finish before the database is updated and thus the UI. This leads to it looking like the UI does not react to inputs immediately.

I wanted to move to cloud functions so I would only have to write the logic once but is this a use case that will not work? (Updating UI elements in real time). Is it worth while trying to set up a cron job to keep pinging my functions to keep them "alive" at all times? How do I increase the functions "alive time" after a cold start since mine seem to die fairly quickly? Any general tips or tricks on tackling this problem?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Are there any examples of projects that have used this methodology? With UI elements that are updated in real time.

Comment: I don't know, try doing some google searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't effectively control the cold start behavior of Cloud Functions.  This is something you will have to accept as a tradeoff.

The only thing you can effectively do is minimize the amount of work in the global scope for your functions and move that work inside each function as necessary.  This creates a situation where each function has its own cold start behavior, which is not shared or duplicated among all your functions.

Comment: I don't think I currently have any global work, some functions do call one helper function I made in the index.js file though.